# How to insert 10 of interval '10 minute' in object array using jdbcTemplate

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

My query is :

```
final String sSelectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADMIN.SESSION_TBL WHERE lastmodified > (NOW() - INTERVAL '"
                + userSessionExpireTime + " MINUTE') AND userid= ?  ";
        return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sSelectQuery, new Object[]{userId}, Integer.class);
```

where in userSessionExpireTime = 10.
If i want to achieve the same thing without appending variable userSessionExpireTime, and putting "?" instead.
How can I achieve it ?

I tried :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ADMIN.SESSION_TBL WHERE lastmodified > (NOW() - INTERVAL '? MINUTE') AND userid= ? 

return getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sSelectQuery, new Object[]{userSessionExpireTime,userId}, Integer.class);
```

but I am getting column out of range.

Can some one please help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `make_interval()`

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ADMIN.SESSION_TBL 
WHERE lastmodified > NOW() - make_interval(mins => ?) 
AND userid = ?
```

If Spring JDBC template chokes on the `=>` operator use the variant without named parameters:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ADMIN.SESSION_TBL 
WHERE lastmodified > NOW() - make_interval(0,0,0,0,0,?) 
AND userid = ?
```